# border-radius not working properly on swiper.js carousel container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Controller, Thumbs } from "swiper";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
import "./index.css";

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Controller, Thumbs]);

function App() {
  const slides = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    slides.push(
      <SwiperSlide key={`slide-${i}`} tag="li">
        <img
          src={`https://picsum.photos/id/${i + 1}/500/300`}
          style={{ listStyle: "none" }}
          alt={`Slide ${i}`}
        />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Swiper
        id="main"
        // thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
        // controller={{ control: controlledSwiper }}
        tag="section"
        wrapperTag="ul"
        navigation
        pagination
        spaceBetween={0}
        slidesPerView={1}
        onInit={(swiper) => console.log("Swiper initialized!", swiper)}
        onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
          console.log("Slide index changed to: ", swiper.activeIndex);
        }}
        onReachEnd={() => console.log("Swiper end reached")}
      >
        {slides}
      </Swiper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS code

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url(./images/next.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url(./images/previous.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center;
}

.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-button-prev:after {
  content: "";
}
```

border-radius property is not working on swiper-container or any classes in it. If I put it on image tag it does not work properly when viewing next or previous image. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?
here is the link of the project of what I have done till now.
https://wizardly-franklin-fdeb17.netlify.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some extra height of `.swiper-container` from top & bottom.

[image]

If you can reduce the height of `.swiper-container` to the label of images in the slider, and then (only then) can add `border-radius: 15px;` and `overflow: hidden;` to `.swiper-container`, I really hope you could find what you're looking for. Please lemme know if you try this.

Comment: I removed the extra height. and it works but the rounded corners of bottom right and left are not visible. They are half cut it seems. How can I fix that ?

Comment: That's because there is still some extra space in the bottom, see the screenshot - https://prnt.sc/v7va1p

Comment: I am not able to understand where that extra spacing is coming of ?

Comment: me neither bro, that's why I just told you about it, if I knew I would do that for you

Comment: another thing, add `border-radius: 15px; overflow: hidden;` to `.swiper-slide` class too, that will make the images rounded even while sliding, now it's not rounded while sliding, see - https://prnt.sc/v7vcso

Comment: Can you add a specific `height` to `.swiper-slide` like `height: 300px;` if you can do this it will reduce that little space from the bottom https://prnt.sc/v7vvol , and after that add `border-radius: 15px; overflow: hidden;` that will make the images while sliding, I did it all by inspecting, see - https://prnt.sc/v7vwlw

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden`  and `border-radius` to the `.swiper` class (the container of the slide) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the borderRadius property directly to the image.

```
<img style={{ listStyle: "none", borderRadius: "15px"}} src={`https://picsum.photos/id/${i + 1}/500/300`} alt={`Slide ${i}`}/>
```

Comment: It works. But when I click on next or previous button, it goes back to normal for small time and then border-radius works. I have updated the link.

Comment: How to fix that issue

Comment: This is normal, it's the transition. You will always see a gap because the border has a radius. It does not go back to normal, it's the transition between 2 images.

Comment: Is there any way to fix that even while transition ?

Comment: No, because if you want a border-radius on an image, it is normal to see the missing piece during transitions, because of the radius. That's why people never add border-radius to Swipers

Answer (score 0):

Test the !important way

```
  border-radius: 15px !important;
```

Comment: not working, I just tested, I have no !dea why it's not working, following the post anyway

Comment: see if you don't have other swiper-container in CSS that is overlapping yours. Maybe try the answer given before mine, is not the best option cause if you want to use swiper in other location you have to put the css again, but maybe will help for now.

Comment: I saw the link you put, and the border is round. You made it? https://wizardly-franklin-fdeb17.netlify.app/

Comment: But when I click on next or previous button, it goes back to normal for small time and then border-radius works. I have updated the link

Comment: The only way not to have that "gap" is to also put the border in the swiper  that does not seem to work. I can't test your code but you are importing two CSS files, you sure that they don't have both the code for that swiper? 
the same you put in the img (style for border) try put it on the <SwiperSlide> too... maybe hides that gap. Sorry can't be more helpful

Comment: The only css I have used in this project I have shared that. Other than that I didnt use any css.  Styles.css is the css file I have written and I have shared that. Swiper-bundle css is the one provided by the swiper library.

Comment: The SwiperSlide is with the border but its height is bigger than the image : https://i.ibb.co/1s75Qw3/swiper.png , put it in red so you can see how it is in the background